# Salvar os dados em um polygonfield

Tags: python, django, geolocalização

boa noite,

Estou implementando um projeto usando django e tenho o seguinte model:

```
class ModelExample(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField("Cidade", max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField("Estado", max_length=2, blank=True)
    polygon = gis_models.PolygonField(default='POLYGON EMPTY')
```

e tenho o json do link abaixo: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyD3VO8vvIb1fAuDANRgI3XbpUslKktB0i4

A ideia é sempre pesquisar via pointfields de outro model se determinado bairro está contido na cidade. Seria algo do tipo ModelExample.objects.get(polygon__contains=OutroModel.point)

Minha grande dúvida é como salvar os dados do json (nodo [geometry][bounds]) no polygonfield?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando o app https://github.com/znc-sistemas/django-municipios. Com ele tenho models prontos para manipular dados de cidades e estados do Brasil e ele possui um arquivo shp pronto com dados do ibge como as coordenadas geográficas de cada cidade do brasil. Uma vez importado tal arquivo (usando o comando python manage.py loaddata nomedoarquivoshp) bastou utilizar as funções prontas do GeoDjango que as pesquisas por ruas existentes ou não em uma cidade funcionaram corretamente.